# body width in samsung galaxy note 10.1

Tags: html, css, galaxy-tab

I have a problem with the displaying pages [of my project](http://www.kuenstleralm.com) in tablet "Galaxy note 10.1". The page doesn't have full width background-image of body element, neither for example footer element. In every browser this worked well, but not in Galaxy tablet. I've never optimized for tablets and I don't know how to find solution for this bug.

Is there way to set width of element to 100% in galaxy note?

Thank Piklis

Comment: [whathaveyoutried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: set width and height of elements body to width 100%, but its correct. I tried add border 1px to body element, and in galaxy tab was border about 25px form right side (but content overflow this and was full sized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You are talking about

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```